# Detect notes of piano using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, fft

I'm having some trouble to understand the output of the `FFT` of a piano note (`A1, f=55 Hz`).

I was expecting to get a "strong" frequency at `55 Hz`, but instead I'm getting a "strong" frequency at `220 Hz`, which correspond to a `A3`, two octaves up.

This is the code I'm using:

```
[audio,fs] = audioread('a1.wav');
audio      = audio(:,1)./max(audio(:,1));
dt         = 1/fs;
t          = linspace(0, length(audio)/fs, length(audio));
T          = max(t);
fftAudio   = fftshift(fft(audio));
mfft       = abs(fftAudio);
pfft       = angle(fftAudio)*(180/pi);
f          = linspace(-fs/2,fs/2,length(fftAudio));
%%
figure,plot(f,mfft,'m.-'),grid on
xlim([0 fs/2])
```

Either I'm doing something wrong of somehow MATLAB "ignores" the low frequencies. 
There's the FFT: 
[image]

This is zoom in FFT:

[image: FFT]

Does anyone know why this is happening? 
Thank you.

Comment: The `plot` command doesn't correspond to the figure you're showing. Please show how you plot `mfft`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo done.

Comment: are you sure your data is right? Everything looks fine. You frequency bins a shift a little but no big deal. Should be `f = -fs/2:fs/Nfft:fs/2-fs/Nfft;`

Comment: What is the sampling frequency? maybe audioread give you the wrong one.

Comment: @TwistedSim fs = 16000 Hz. Why?

Comment: If 16kHz is the right sampling frequency for your signal, then there is a frequency of 220 Hz in it. Your code seems okay.

Answer (score 0):

You have merely discovered that some pianos produces sets of strong harmonic overtones with occasionally weak fundamental frequency spectrum (effects that might possibly be caused by string diameter and stiffness, soundboard resonance energy swaps, or microphone response and placement).

Some reading on the physics of musical instruments, and the psychoacoustics of human hearing might help.